# Связывание таблиц в новой версии Grails 2.4.3

Tags: веб-программирование, java, intellij-idea

Добрый день. Версии сего фрэймворка выходят часто, я не кодил на нем с версии 2.3.7, что было около месяца назад. С того времени что-то изменилось, да так, что при простом связывании таблиц hasOne система выдает ошибки:

```
"Error 2014-08-06 22:23:46,521 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table profile drop constraint FK_c1dkiawnlj6uoe6fnlwd6j83j if exists
| Error 2014-08-06 22:23:46,524 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Таблица "PROFILE" не найдена
Table "PROFILE" not found; SQL statement:
alter table profile drop constraint FK_c1dkiawnlj6uoe6fnlwd6j83j if exists [42102-176]"
```

Связываю таблицы старым способом, как все работало и работает(!) на весрии 2.3.7, пример ниже:

```
class User {
    String username
    static hasOne = [profile: Profile]
    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Profile {
    String info
    User user
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Использую встроенную БД. Код в Intellij IDEA 13.1. Данный эксепшен гуглил, информации нету. Буду благодарен за помощь.

P.S Оговорюсь, что таким же способом в версии 2.3.7 все работает гладко.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке, название твоей таблицы Profile в бд не "PROFILE", так что попробуй указать это название явно:

```
class Profile {
String info
User user
static constraints = {
}
 static mapping = {
    table 'PROFILE'
   }
}
```